# how to bind image and video in img and video tag dynamically

Tags: angular

I have a page where i am showing images and videos on a page. I am getting image and video path in same variable as shown below

```
    Media: Array(3)
 0: {ImagePath: "http://13.232.25.79:4105/files/20/prow-featured.jpg", LikeCount: 0, 
 Comment: ""}
 1: {ImagePath: "http://13.232.25.79:4105/files/20/7051252eae6820fd3309120d72fe2978.jpg", 
 LikeCount: 0, Comment: ""}
 2: {ImagePath: "http://13.232.25.79:4105/files/20/Investor.mp4", LikeCount: 0, Comment: ""}
```

How can i differentiate image and video path so that they can be put in their respective image and video tag.

*my component.html*

```
    <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let candidateMedia of sharedMedia">
     <div>
    <p style="color: aliceblue">{{candidateMedia.Candidates.FirstName }} 
    {{candidateMedia.Candidates.LastName }} shares following post</p>
    <div *ngIf = "candidateMedia.Media">
    <img *ngFor="let media of candidateMedia.Media" src="{{media.ImagePath}}">
      <video src="{{media.ImagePath}}" controls></video> 
     </div>
     </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here. I would have thought your array should have had pairs of URLs. One for image, the other for the video?

Comment: Image and video are coming from same variable that is ImagePath

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#Multiple_sources_example poster attribute perhaps?